# How much is a Trek Alpha aluminium 58cm road bike worth?

Tags: road-bike

Someone sold me a Trek road bike for $200. The bike says Alpha Aluminium on the frame and the front forks say Bontrager. I tried looking it up on the internet but didn't have much luck. I'm looking for any info about this bike.

Comment: Well, scrap aluminum goes for about $0.40 a pound, and I'd guess there's maybe 8 pounds of aluminum in the frame.

Comment: https://www.google.com.au/search?q=Trek+Alpha+Aluminium

Comment: Well you just bought it for $200, so it's safe to say the going rate for that bike is about $200. What's your real question? Are you wanting to know how much you **should** have paid for it?

Comment: Bontrager is a good brand, trek has good and bad models.  More importantly, is it comfortable to ride?  Will you enjoy riding it?

Comment: How about a pic?

Comment: We should put "no valuation questions" in FAQ because they're inherently unanswerable. The value is specific to the seller and the buyer.

Comment: Actually, Trek are one of the best manufacturers at maintaining their back-catalogue online, so you haven't looked hard enough. The Alpha is an alu frame with the same geometry as the Madone, but it comes in many variations and the value of any one bike will depend on the groupset installed. Higher-end models (I had a 2.3, all 105) retailed at over $1000 around 5 years ago. All the Bontrager stuff was standard across the range I think.

Answer (score 2):

It's worth $200.  That's the price a willing buyer just paid a willing seller for that bike in your area.

If you have some more information about it, you might try looking it up at http://www.bicyclebluebook.com/SearchBikes.aspx.